# How to prevent AgGrid form making last child expandable when doing row grouping

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

We're using the Row Group Panel to do row grouping in AgGrid. It already works but there remains one bug: A row without any further children can be expanded by clicking on (A) (see screenshot below) - but this makes no sense cause there is nothing grouped in this row. Even worse, when you click on it there opens a random grey area (B). Does anyone know hot to avoid showing the expand button (A) on a row which does not group anything?

While I want to avoid the expand button to be shown we still need the checkbox on that level (C).

I didn't show any configuration because I don't know which one is relevant and there would be too much code to include.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself. The behavior was caused by the following configuration:

```
<AgGridReact
  ...
  detailRowHeight={300}
  masterDetail
  ...
  ...
```

`masterDetail` (which means masterDetail ist activated) causes expand button (A) is visible. The `detailRowHeight` causes the grey area (B) to show up. But when you remove `masterDetail` also the checkbox (C) vanishes.

Since I want to keep checkbox (C) my compromise is to leave `masterDetail` activated and just set `detailRowHeight={0}`. Doing this avoids the grey area but (unfortunately) leaves the expand button still visible. If anybody knows a better solution which also hides the expand button feel free to answer.